# AngularJS crashes when I define a route with two parameters in it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

As per the title, as soon as I add the route:

```
    .when('/cluster/:clusterName/node/:nodeId', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/node/view.html',
      controller: nodeViewController
    })
```

and try to access it, the browser tab crashes with this in the JavaScript console:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6695:34)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6086:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6089:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6089:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6089:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:5982:30)
    at link (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js:919:7)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6692:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:6086:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:5982:30) <div class="col-lg-12 ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

I don't understand why this happens and don't really know to debug it further as I am new to AngularJS. Here is my full app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dopeFrontend', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .run(function($http, $rootScope, $location) {
      //$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $('input[name=_csrf_token]').val();
      $rootScope.location = $location;
    })
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/core/clusters.html',
              controller: indexController
            })
            .when('/login', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/auth/login.html',
              controller: loginController
            })
            .when('/create', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/core/create_cluster.html',
              controller: clusterCreateController
            })
            .when('/connect', {
              controller: clusterConnectController
            })
            .when('/cluster/:clusterName', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/cluster/overview.html',
              controller: clusterOverviewController
            })
            .when('/cluster/:clusterName/nodes', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/node/nodes.html',
              controller: nodesViewController
            })
            .when('/cluster/:clusterName/node/add', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/node/add.html',
              controller: nodeAddController
            })
            .when('/cluster/:clusterName/node/:nodeId', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/node/view.html',
              controller: nodeViewController
            })
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
      }]);
```

I am using AngularJS 1.2.22, Google Chrome 36.0.1985.125 and the AngularJS app is served through a local Nginx server. Here's the relevant config:

```
root   /Users/alex/dev/dope/dope/static;
index index.html;

location / {
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

How can I fix this or debug it further?

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: 1.2.22, sorry, I added it to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Lets me guess, you might have a nested `ng-view` in `partials/node/view.html` file.

Comment: @runTarm, no, that template is actually empty at the moment. I only have one ng-view in my base index.html template.

Comment: Does the issue still exist if the `html5Mode` is turned off?

Comment: Just a hunch: your last two routes introduce an ambiguity, in that the add node route can't be distinguished from the "node details" route.  Try changing the add node route URL to something like /cluster/:clusterName/add-node

Comment: @runTarm, good catch, this fixes the issue. Thank you! Could've sworn I tried that. Why does html5mode causes this issue though?

Comment: @admiralobvious It's interesting that disabling html5Mode fixes the problem. Disabling that adds "#!" to all of your URL's which may not be desirable. I think my previous comment still stands (and may allow you to enable html5Mode). Think about it: when the URL is `/cluster/:clusterName/node/add` is that supposed to match the "add node" route, or should it match the "node details" route where the `:nodeId` parameter is the string "add"? Again, just a hunch, I haven't really looked at the source code ;)

Comment: May be try adding `<base href="." />` or `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>` into the head, it might helps.

Comment: runTarm The script does, thanks again! @Sunil D., I had tried that, even with node/:nodeId by itself it would still crash.

Comment: Interesting, I'm now wondering why it is not mentioned in the documentation of [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found that the `<base>` tag is required for relative urls in HTML5 mode.

It is mentioned in this documentation [$location guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> **Relative links**
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must either specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) or you must use absolute urls (starting with `/`) everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often different from the root of the application.
>
> Running Angular apps with the History API enabled from document root is strongly encouraged as it takes care of all relative link issues.